# How to read Json files properly in Unity?

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

I read [this article](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-read-json-file.401306/) and try it.

I wrote a very simple code to read the json file:

```
void Start()
{
    Debug.Log(evolution.text);
    try
    {
        EvolutionDic = JsonUtility.FromJson<Dictionary<string, string>>(evolution.text);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e.Message);
    }

    Debug.Log(EvolutionDic.Count);
}
```

The code read the `evolution.text` correctly, but didn't write into the dictionary.

I had tested the Json file in Visual C# and have no problem reading it into the dictionary.

Could somebody please be so kind and tell me where did I do wrong!?

Much appreciated!

Result Snapshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries aren't natively serializable/deserializable.

- But you can use [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) that I think it works with dictionaries, or any other third party serializer (which is probably what you do in your test Visual C# example).
- Implement your own [serialization/deserialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization-Custom.html) method for your
  structure.